# Adding a visit list

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to mark a list of objects that are visited. I'm beginner in C# and programming. 
So I'm iterating over a list of objects, check their distance to a plane, then I save them. but I need to check if that object has been visited or no..

The problem is in visitedTrees, I need to save them there so that I exit when I have visited all the tree objects.

```
HashSet<Vector3> visitedTrees = new HashSet<Vector3>();
var stripes = new Dictionary<int, List<Transform>>();
int stripeNumber = 0;

cameraPlane.SetNormalAndPosition(normal, view.camera.transform.position + normal * minDistance);

int visited = 0;

while (true)
{
     bool reachedFarTree = false;

     foreach (var gameObject in trees)
     {
         float distance = cameraPlane.GetDistanceToPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
         Debug.Log("distances " + Mathf.Abs(distance));
         if (Mathf.Abs(distance) < 20)
         {
             List<Transform> treeStripes;
             if (!stripes.TryGetValue(stripeNumber, out treeStripes))
             {
                 treeStripes = new List<Transform>();
                 stripes[stripeNumber] = treeStripes;
             }

             treeStripes.Add(gameObject.transform);
             if (!visitedTrees.Contains(gameObject.transform))
             {
                 visitedTrees.Add(gameObject.transform.position);
                 visited++;
             }
         }

         if (visited == visitedTrees.Count)
         {
             reachedFarTree = true;
         }
     }
     offset += 20;
     cameraPlane.SetNormalAndPosition(normal, view.camera.transform.position + normal * offset);
     stripeNumber++;
     if(reachedFarTree)
         break;         
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you're adding them to the `visitedTrees` when you're visiting, so you just need to know if `visitedTrees` contains a node? That's just `.Contains` - which you're already using. So I'm confused: what exactly do you need to do that you're not already?

Comment: Rup, yes but contains doesn't work, it gives a compilation error

Comment: isnt gameObject.transform a matrix and not a vector3?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger yes it's a matrix

Comment: Therefor this line gives the error?  if (!visitedTrees.Contains(gameObject.transform))

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger yes

Comment: You can see the problem now?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger contains will have a Vector3, but do you think is it ok to check for vector3 for marking visited ?

Comment: if (visited == visitedTrees.Count) will always be true... so it will exit the loop

Comment: no but make the hashset of type Transform or whatever the type of gameObject.transform is... or check for gameObject.transform.position instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you instantiate:

```
HashSet<Vector3> visitedTrees = new HashSet<Vector3>();
```

and then you try to lookup:

```
if (!visitedTrees.Contains(gameObject.transform))
```

where as gameObject.Transform is of type Transform (a Matrix) and the HashSet can only contain Vector3 objects.

Instead instanciate:

```
HashSet<Transform> visitedTrees = new HashSet<Transform>();
```

**OR**

```
 if (!visitedTrees.Contains(gameObject.transform.position))
 {
      visitedTrees.Add(gameObject.transform.position);
      visited++;
 }
```

**Edit**

```
  HashSet<Vector3> visitedTrees = new HashSet<Vector3>();
  var stripes = new Dictionary<int, List<Transform>>();
  int stripeNumber = 0;

  cameraPlane.SetNormalAndPosition(normal, view.camera.transform.position + normal * minDistance);

  int visited = 0;

  while (true)
  {
      bool reachedFarTree = false;

      foreach (var gameObject in trees)
      {
          float distance = cameraPlane.GetDistanceToPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
          Debug.Log("distances " + Mathf.Abs(distance));
          if (Mathf.Abs(distance) < 20 + offset)
          {
              List<Transform> treeStripes;
              if (!stripes.TryGetValue(stripeNumber, out treeStripes))
              {
                  treeStripes = new List<Transform>();
                  stripes[stripeNumber] = treeStripes;
              }

              treeStripes.Add(gameObject.transform);
              if (!visitedTrees.Contains(gameObject.transform.position))
              {
                  visitedTrees.Add(gameObject.transform.position);
                  visited++;
              }
           }


      }
      if (trees.Count >= visited)
      {
          reachedFarTree = true;
      }

      offset += 20; // may try for a smaller value
      cameraPlane.SetNormalAndPosition(normal, view.camera.transform.position + normal * offset);
            stripeNumber++;
       if (reachedFarTree)
          break;
   }
```

Comment: will contains work and really check if I already visited that tree based on the vector3 ?

Comment: i have no clue how vector3 in unity checks for equality but in managed directx it does properly... guess you have to try ... if not we have to dive deeper into our box of tricks =)

Comment: it might not... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/395513/vector3-comparison-efficiency-and-float-precision.html

Comment: @ahmedragia try if it aint working leave a comment and we dive deeper

Comment: also this condition is always true if (visited == visitedTrees.Count)

Comment: let me have a look at the algorithm itself too... give me a few

Comment: yeah these values will allways be the same.... since you add an item and increment in the same block

Comment: thanks for help. but how would I solve the problem with that conditional logic error

Comment: i dont get what the algorithm is supposed to do exactly... for example what's that offset is supposed to do

Comment: I have few trees(vector3), I move a plane then check the distance, if they are close to that plane, I added them to list, and mark them as visited. Then I offset that plane little bit, then I test the trees if they are closer to that plane, then I add them, I do it again and again, until I should visit all the trees

Comment: from what i see here is that every gameObject that has a distance lower than 20 gets added to the HashSet as well as to the Dictionary and the loop breaks... what's it supposed to do?

Comment: I check each gameobject(tree) and check if it has a distance lower than 20 infront of the plane, then I add them to hashset<-- visited, and a dictionary that I use later to process a group of trees

Comment: you never used that offset and the condition for the breaking of the outer loop was a bit out of place